# How to custom sort function in javascript or other method?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var cars = ["a", "c", "s", "r"];
function mysort() {

document.getElementById("show_cars").innerHTML = cars;}
```

I hope my output result is sort by c,a,r,s

```
//output
c,a,r,s
```

anyidea how to do this??? thank you very much

Comment: what is the logic behind the sorting you want?

Comment: *I hope my out result is sort by c,a,r,s* Why? If the result is predefined, then why go through the trouble of sorting anyways?

Comment: Probably an XY problem ..? You need to detect, if you can form the word "cars" from the letters in the array, and you only assumed, that sorting is the way to go ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one object to define order of each letter and sort by that object.

```js
var cars = ["a", "c", "r", "s"];
var s = {c: 1, a: 2, r: 3, s: 4}
var r = cars.sort((a, b) => s[a] - s[b]).join(',')

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should implement your own custom function and pass it to the array sort function. 
Your custom function should have the criteria to order the elements in the array.

```
var cars = ["a", "c", "r", "s"];
cars.sort(function(a, b) {
   //Return the result of comparing your a and b elements.
   return result;
});
console.log(cars.join(""));
```